# Azure DNS bulk import

Tags: azure, dns, azure-powershell

I need to import over 100 A records in a zone by way of CSV (hopefully quicker)

The technet articles only addresses one record at a time using the following commands

New-AzureRmDnsRecordSet and New-AzureRmDnsRecordSet

```
$Records = @()
$Records += New-AzureRmDnsRecordConfig -IPv4Address 1.2.3.4
$RecordSet = New-AzureRmDnsRecordSet -Name "www" -RecordType A -ResourceGroupName "MyResourceGroup" -TTL 3600 -ZoneName "myzone.com" -DnsRecords $Records
```

Do either of those cmdlets support such an operation?

Comment: Cloud you please tell us the source format of your DNS records? You may need to write a Powershell script to update these records.

Comment: The Azure CLI includes a zone file import.